# PayUMoney Implementations in Android

Tags: android, payment-gateway

I am integrating PayUMoney in Eclipse IDE Android with these link:
https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-Custom-Browser
https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Android-Custom-Browser/wiki

I am facing few problems, while integrating:

1. null pointer exception:

   ```
   getIntent().getExtras().getString("postData").split("&");
   ```

   I didn't find any class in Custom-Browser where this string is passed.
2. error:

   ```
   @Override
   public void updateSet(Set<String> urlSet,String check){
       if (urlSet != null && urlSet.size() > 0 && webviewUrl!=null && !urlSet.contains(webviewUrl)) {
           progressBarVisibilityPayuChrome(View.GONE);
       }
       set=urlSet;
       checkValue=check;
   }
   ```

   It is not an override Method.

Comment: Those urls are not accessible, little more about code like which class its extending would help

Comment: You need to contact PayuMoney guys for understanding SDK part.

Comment: hey please send me these SDKs to my email id sritamjagadev@outlook.com......